# background image is not being displayed in div

Tags: css, html

I am working in angular 5 project using VS Code.
I am unable to get image on display but it is being download because it is in the network tab in developer tool of chrome browser. This means url is right.

```
.start {
    background: #222 url('/assets/images/Untitled-1.png') center center no-repeat;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now added width and height to the parent div, still no image on display ;(

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    <div class="start"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is downloaded but not being displayed. Where did I mistake?

I am following that [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4tbhwMGSPQ&list=PLUoqTnNH-2XyNhhLuYrrmrmV46jVw6RHF&index=4)

Comment: height:100% --> height:0 : no content inside the div and no height specfied to the parent element

Comment: also a typo mistake `background: #222 url('/assets/images/Untitled-1.png') center center no-repeat;` missing a `,`

Comment: There's no Angular content there. Post you Angular code, or remove the tag !

Comment: where comma should be placed?

Comment: after the color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using background property to set an image you need to have content inside that will increase elements height or set a specific height yourself.

Comment: look now, I have added width and height to the parent div

Comment: @mwn you added height:100% to parent and the same logic apply, no height for its parent so height will be auto and nothing will happen

Comment: @mwn you can't use percentage based heights if there is not content. You need to use some of the specific units. px, em, rem, wv, wh etc.. You can't set %

Comment: @NikolaDragan no he CAN use % BUT % will refer to parent height so parent height need to be set

Comment: @TemaniAfif not in the example he is showing. I know you can use it if the parent has it set, but it doesn't seem like it in his example.

Comment: it works, I've added some html elements to the div which is setting background image

Comment: because he didn't set a height .. he set a height of 100% to parent and the logic is the same for the parent because its parent has also no height set. So doing a cascading 100% height will work only if we have the first one with a height set or we reach the document element

Comment: please guys, upvote so that I can get some privileges and advantages on this site. right now I can not even upvote to this answer ;(. Thanks for your input